How to get mouse position with Rete.js
I am looking for a way to add a listener to my editor so that when I hover it with my mouse, I can get my the position of my mouse. I am hoping that by doing so it would give me the coordinate of my mouse with the referential of the editor which places the center (0,0) in the middle and therefore makes it possible to have negative coordinates.
I saw that it was possible with Rete.js v1 through with the mouseMove event and something about getting the mouse position through area.view but I cannot really find anything working for REte.js V2.
